# Finding it difficult to create a table in Authorea

Tags: code

I am new to LaTex and using Authorea for editing a script. When I create a table, I am getting the error. Authorea is displaying this table. However, I am unable to export it to PDF, as there is some error with the code. When I export the tex file and running it on Texmaker, I am getting the pdf. Can you help me on this error?

Sample Code:

```
\begin{table*}
\caption{\label{tab:table1}Summary Table}
\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7}
\small
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\hline
Method & Head 1 & Head 2 & Head 3 & Head 4 & Head 5\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Model: FF3F}}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{\alpha}}\\
Method A & -0.2703 & -0.00248 & 0.0490 & 0.1743 & 0.1921\\
Method A  & -0.2706 & -0.00215 & 0.0498 & -0.1726 & 0.1960\\
Method A  & -0.2706 & -0.00215 & 0.0497 & -0.1732 & 0.1948\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table*}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small, compilable document, which we can test on our PC with our editors.

Comment: You have error in `\multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{\alpha}}\\`. Missed is math environment and correct command for bold symbols..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has error, as I already told you in the my second comment below question. `\alpha` had to be in math environment. So I suspect that your editor has nothing with your error.

See, if the following MWE (Minimal Working Example) works at you:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
\caption{\label{tab:table1}Summary Table}
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
\begin{tabular}{l   S[table-format=-1.4]
                    S[table-format=-1.5]
                    S[table-format= 1.4]
                    S[table-format=-1.4]
                    S[table-format= 1.4]
                }
    \toprule
Method & {Head 1} & {Head 2} & {Head 3} & {Head} 4 & {Head} 5\\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Model: FF3F}}\\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{l}{$\bm{\alpha}$}\\
Method A  & -0.2703 & -0.00248 & 0.0490 &  0.1743 & 0.1921\\
Method A  & -0.2706 & -0.00215 & 0.0498 & -0.1726 & 0.1960\\
Method A  & -0.2706 & -0.00215 & 0.0497 & -0.1732 & 0.1948\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I took some library in a wee bit rewrite your table code. For columns with numbers I use `S` column type defined in the `siunitx` package, then use normal font size and employ `bm` package for boldface math symbols.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Your efforts are much helpful for me.